# un-even margins after <a> tag in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, margin

I am writing a URG-8 HTML file. It is giving proper output in Mozilla Firefox but in Chrome it gives un-even margins to the left of the  tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Ajax Example</title>
    <style>
    .option{text-align:right; font-family: 'JameelNooriNastaleeq','Jameel Noori Nastaleeq','nafeesnastaleeqregular1','Nafees Nastaleeq'; font-size:18px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
۞‌( )
<a href='#'  id='1_0_0_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>حضر</a><ul id='menu_1_0_0_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('1_0_0_all','حضر')"><span class='option'>حضر</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('1_0_0_all','خصر')"><span class='option'>خصر</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('1_0_0_all','خصو')"><span class='option'>خصو</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('1_0_0_all','حضو')"><span class='option'>حضو</span></li></ul> ب بلا<a href='#'  id='1_0_5_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>ل</a><ul id='menu_1_0_5_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('1_0_5_all','ل')"><span class='option'>ل</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('1_0_5_all','مل')"><span class='option'>مل</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('1_0_5_all','لص')"><span class='option'>لص</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('1_0_5_all','ں')"><span class='option'>ں</span></li></ul> بن <a href='#'  id='1_0_9_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>ر</a><ul id='menu_1_0_9_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('1_0_9_all','ر')"><span class='option'>ر</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('1_0_9_all','مر')"><span class='option'>مر</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('1_0_9_all','لر')"><span class='option'>لر</span></li></ul>‌باح ۞' <a href='#'  id='1_0_15_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>منی</a><ul id='menu_1_0_15_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('1_0_15_all','ضی')"><span class='option'>ضی</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('1_0_15_all','فعی')"><span class='option'>فعی</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('1_0_15_all','منی')"><span class='option'>منی</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('1_0_15_all','عنی')"><span class='option'>عنی</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('1_0_15_all','نسی')"><span class='option'>نسی</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('1_0_15_all','نہی')"><span class='option'>نہی</span></li></ul> ا۞
یو<a href='#'  id='2_0_1_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>ں</a><ul id='menu_2_0_1_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_1_all','ں')"><span class='option'>ں</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_1_all','لسا')"><span class='option'>لسا</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_1_all','لما')"><span class='option'>لما</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_1_all','لمسا')"><span class='option'>لمسا</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_1_all','ل')"><span class='option'>ل</span></li></ul> تو <a href='#'  id='2_0_5_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>حضر</a><ul id='menu_2_0_5_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_5_all','خصو')"><span class='option'>خصو</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_5_all','حضو')"><span class='option'>حضو</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_5_all','حضر')"><span class='option'>حضر</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_5_all','خصر')"><span class='option'>خصر</span></li></ul>‌ت ز ۞‌وہ پہلے <a href='#'  id='2_0_16_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>غلا</a><ul id='menu_2_0_16_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_16_all','غلا')"><span class='option'>غلا</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_16_all','خلا')"><span class='option'>خلا</span></li></ul>‌م تھے جنہیں <a href='#'  id='2_0_23_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>مشر</a><ul id='menu_2_0_23_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_23_all','مشر')"><span class='option'>مشر</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_23_all','شر')"><span class='option'>شر</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_23_all','شہر')"><span class='option'>شہر</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_23_all','عشر')"><span class='option'>عشر</span></li></ul>‌ف بہ ا<a href='#'  id='2_0_29_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>سلا</a><ul id='menu_2_0_29_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_29_all','سلا')"><span class='option'>سلا</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_29_all','لسلا')"><span class='option'>لسلا</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_29_all','صلا')"><span class='option'>صلا</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_29_all','علا')"><span class='option'>علا</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_29_all','مطا')"><span class='option'>مطا</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_29_all','ھلا')"><span class='option'>ھلا</span></li></ul>‌م ہو<a href='#'  id='2_0_33_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>نے</a><ul id='menu_2_0_33_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_33_all','خے')"><span class='option'>خے</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_33_all','نے')"><span class='option'>نے</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_33_all','فے')"><span class='option'>فے</span></li></ul> <a href='#'  id='2_0_35_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>کا</a><ul id='menu_2_0_35_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_35_all','کا')"><span class='option'>کا</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_35_all','گا')"><span class='option'>گا</span></li></ul> ا<a href='#'  id='2_0_38_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>عز</a><ul id='menu_2_0_38_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_38_all','خر')"><span class='option'>خر</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_38_all','حز')"><span class='option'>حز</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_38_all','عز')"><span class='option'>عز</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_38_all','نحر')"><span class='option'>نحر</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_38_all','غمو')"><span class='option'>غمو</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_38_all','غو')"><span class='option'>غو</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_0_38_all','عنو')"><span class='option'>عنو</span></li></ul>‌از نصیب ہوا
<a href='#'  id='2_1_0_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>لیکن</a><ul id='menu_2_1_0_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_0_all','لیکن')"><span class='option'>لیکن</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_0_all','لیکسن')"><span class='option'>لیکسن</span></li></ul> حقیقت یہ ہے <a href='#'  id='2_1_8_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>کہ</a><ul id='menu_2_1_8_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_8_all','کہ')"><span class='option'>کہ</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_8_all','مکہ')"><span class='option'>مکہ</span></li></ul> انہیں نبیا<a href='#'  id='2_1_15_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>کر</a><ul id='menu_2_1_15_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_15_all','کہو')"><span class='option'>کہو</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_15_all','کر')"><span class='option'>کر</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_15_all','مکر')"><span class='option'>مکر</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_15_all','کمو')"><span class='option'>کمو</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_15_all','کو')"><span class='option'>کو</span></li></ul>‌<a href='#'  id='2_1_16_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>م</a><ul id='menu_2_1_16_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_16_all','م')"><span class='option'>م</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_16_all','سم')"><span class='option'>سم</span></li></ul> <a href='#'  id='2_1_18_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>صلی</a><ul id='menu_2_1_18_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_18_all','صلی')"><span class='option'>صلی</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_18_all','ھلی')"><span class='option'>ھلی</span></li></ul> اللہ علیہ و آلہ و <a href='#'  id='2_1_32_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>سلم</a><ul id='menu_2_1_32_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_32_all','سلم')"><span class='option'>سلم</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_32_all','حلم')"><span class='option'>حلم</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_32_all','مصمم')"><span class='option'>مصمم</span></li></ul> <a href='#'  id='2_1_34_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>نے</a><ul id='menu_2_1_34_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_34_all','خے')"><span class='option'>خے</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_34_all','نے')"><span class='option'>نے</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_34_all','فے')"><span class='option'>فے</span></li></ul> آزاد <a href='#'  id='2_1_41_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>کر</a><ul id='menu_2_1_41_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_41_all','کر')"><span class='option'>کر</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_41_all','کہو')"><span class='option'>کہو</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_41_all','کمو')"><span class='option'>کمو</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_41_all','مکر')"><span class='option'>مکر</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_41_all','کو')"><span class='option'>کو</span></li></ul> دیا <a href='#'  id='2_1_46_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>تھا</a><ul id='menu_2_1_46_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_46_all','تھا')"><span class='option'>تھا</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_46_all','تعد')"><span class='option'>تعد</span></li></ul>‌۔ ا<a href='#'  id='2_1_50_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>گر</a><ul id='menu_2_1_50_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_50_all','گو')"><span class='option'>گو</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_50_all','گر')"><span class='option'>گر</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_50_all','مگر')"><span class='option'>مگر</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_50_all','گمو')"><span class='option'>گمو</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_50_all','مگو')"><span class='option'>مگو</span></li></ul> حقیقی <a href='#'  id='2_1_54_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>معنو</a><ul id='menu_2_1_54_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_54_all','معنو')"><span class='option'>معنو</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_54_all','مفہو')"><span class='option'>مفہو</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_54_all','مغمو')"><span class='option'>مغمو</span></li></ul>‌<a href='#'  id='2_1_55_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>ں</a><ul id='menu_2_1_55_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_55_all','ں')"><span class='option'>ں</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_55_all','لسا')"><span class='option'>لسا</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_55_all','لمسا')"><span class='option'>لمسا</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_55_all','لما')"><span class='option'>لما</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_55_all','ل')"><span class='option'>ل</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_1_55_all','لمعا')"><span class='option'>لمعا</span></li></ul>
<a href='#'  id='2_2_0_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>میں</a><ul id='menu_2_2_0_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_0_all','میں')"><span class='option'>میں</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_0_all','یں')"><span class='option'>یں</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_0_all','لیس')"><span class='option'>لیس</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_0_all','یس')"><span class='option'>یس</span></li></ul> د<a href='#'  id='2_2_3_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>یکھا</a><ul id='menu_2_2_3_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_3_all','یکھا')"><span class='option'>یکھا</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_3_all','مکھیا')"><span class='option'>مکھیا</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_3_all','سیکھا')"><span class='option'>سیکھا</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_3_all','کلیا')"><span class='option'>کلیا</span></li></ul> جائے ۞‌<a href='#'  id='2_2_9_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>حلقہ</a><ul id='menu_2_2_9_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_9_all','حلقہ')"><span class='option'>حلقہ</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_9_all','قلعہ')"><span class='option'>قلعہ</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_9_all','حلتہ')"><span class='option'>حلتہ</span></li></ul> ا<a href='#'  id='2_2_12_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>سلا</a><ul id='menu_2_2_12_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_12_all','سلا')"><span class='option'>سلا</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_12_all','لسلا')"><span class='option'>لسلا</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_12_all','صلا')"><span class='option'>صلا</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_12_all','علا')"><span class='option'>علا</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_12_all','ھلا')"><span class='option'>ھلا</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_12_all','حلا')"><span class='option'>حلا</span></li></ul>‌<a href='#'  id='2_2_13_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>م</a><ul id='menu_2_2_13_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_13_all','م')"><span class='option'>م</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_13_all','سم')"><span class='option'>سم</span></li></ul> <a href='#'  id='2_2_15_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>میں</a><ul id='menu_2_2_15_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_15_all','میں')"><span class='option'>میں</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_15_all','یں')"><span class='option'>یں</span></li></ul> دا<a href='#'  id='2_2_19_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>خل</a><ul id='menu_2_2_19_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_19_all','خل')"><span class='option'>خل</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_19_all','غل')"><span class='option'>غل</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_19_all','فل')"><span class='option'>فل</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_19_all','ضل')"><span class='option'>ضل</span></li></ul> ہو<a href='#'  id='2_2_22_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>نے</a><ul id='menu_2_2_22_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_22_all','خے')"><span class='option'>خے</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_22_all','نے')"><span class='option'>نے</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_22_all','فے')"><span class='option'>فے</span></li></ul> وا<a href='#'  id='2_2_26_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>لے</a><ul id='menu_2_2_26_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_26_all','حے')"><span class='option'>حے</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_26_all','لے')"><span class='option'>لے</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_26_all','نے')"><span class='option'>نے</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_26_all','لمے')"><span class='option'>لمے</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_26_all','ملے')"><span class='option'>ملے</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_26_all','عے')"><span class='option'>عے</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_26_all','ے')"><span class='option'>ے</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_26_all','تے')"><span class='option'>تے</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_26_all','طے')"><span class='option'>طے</span></li></ul> پہلے <a href='#'  id='2_2_30_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>غلا</a><ul id='menu_2_2_30_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_30_all','غلا')"><span class='option'>غلا</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_30_all','خلا')"><span class='option'>خلا</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_30_all','فلا')"><span class='option'>فلا</span></li></ul>‌<a href='#'  id='2_2_31_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>م</a><ul id='menu_2_2_31_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_31_all','م')"><span class='option'>م</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_31_all','سم')"><span class='option'>سم</span></li></ul>' <a href='#'  id='2_2_34_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>سیا</a><ul id='menu_2_2_34_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_34_all','سیا')"><span class='option'>سیا</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_34_all','صیا')"><span class='option'>صیا</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_34_all','حیا')"><span class='option'>حیا</span></li></ul>‌ہ فام <a href='#'  id='2_2_40_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>مگر</a><ul id='menu_2_2_40_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_40_all','مگر')"><span class='option'>مگر</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_40_all','گو')"><span class='option'>گو</span></li></ul> رو<a href='#'  id='2_2_44_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>شن</a><ul id='menu_2_2_44_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_44_all','شن')"><span class='option'>شن</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_44_all','کشنا')"><span class='option'>کشنا</span></li></ul> د<a href='#'  id='2_2_47_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>ل</a><ul id='menu_2_2_47_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_47_all','ل')"><span class='option'>ل</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_47_all','مل')"><span class='option'>مل</span></li></ul> <a href='#'  id='2_2_49_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>حضر</a><ul id='menu_2_2_49_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_49_all','حضر')"><span class='option'>حضر</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_49_all','خصر')"><span class='option'>خصر</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_49_all','مغر')"><span class='option'>مغر</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_49_all','عفر')"><span class='option'>عفر</span></li></ul>‌<a href='#'  id='2_2_50_all' style='color:#ff0000; text-align:right; text-decoration:none' class='checkit'>ت</a><ul id='menu_2_2_50_all'  class='jeegoocontext cm_default' style='display:none'><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_50_all','مت')"><span class='option'>مت</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_50_all','ت')"><span class='option'>ت</span></li><li style='text-align:right' onClick="updatevalue('2_2_50_all','لت')"><span class='option'>لت</span></li></ul>
بلا ۞‌تھے۔
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you using a css reset to normalize all margins and such?

Comment: What on earth?  @TJ is right, I don't see any margins at all, it's just text.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, wrap your entire content in a `<div>` and apply `text-align:justify`

```
div{
 text-align:justify;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/KxQH7/)

*Side note: please avoid using inline styles - [Why Use CSS @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS)*